# AutoFixture, NSubstitute, xUnit with ClassData

Tags: xunit, nsubstitute, autofixture

I am using AutoFixture with NSubstitute and xUnit.

I have the following attribute implementations:

```
public class AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute()
        : base(() => new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization()))
    {
    }
}

public class AutoNSubstituteClassDataAttribute : CompositeDataAttribute
{
    public AutoNSubstituteClassDataAttribute(Type @class)
        : base(
            new ClassDataAttribute(@class),
            new AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute())
    {
    }
}
```

**Issue**

When I am trying to use `[AutoNSubstituteClassData]` regarding the test case parameters everything works fine (ie: all parameters are passing OK, including the auto mocked parameters), however the `Theory` **is only called once**, regardless the `Count()` of `IEnumerable`

Here is the code of Theory, and the ClassData:

```
// Issue: called only once, despite of TestClass1 yields twice
[Theory]
[AutoNSubstituteClassData(typeof(TestClass1))]
public void AutoNSubstituteClassData_AutoFixture_Injects(string dummy,
    string actualConcrete,
    ITestInterface1 actualMock)
{
    // Assert
    dummy.Should().Be("dummy");
    // 1) I do not blow the sample with AssertInjected, all is OK, actualConcrete is an expected auto generated string, and actualMock is an expected NSubstitute mock
    // 2) If I comment out AssertInjected the issue is still there.
    AssertInjected(actualConcrete, actualMock);
}

public class TestClass1 : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[] {"dummy"};
        yield return new object[] {"dummy"};
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

**Question**

Why the `[Theory]` runs only once, despite the TestClass1 yields twice?

Answer (score 0):

Answering the asked question: [Theory] is xUnit attribute. As per their documentation:
"If the data source contains multiple rows, then the test method is executed multiple times (once with each data row)."

There is only one data row in the usage above :

```
[Theory]
[AutoNSubstituteClassData(typeof(TestClass1))]
```

To make the test run twice:

```
[Theory]
[AutoNSubstituteClassData(typeof(TestClass1))]
[AutoNSubstituteClassData(typeof(TestClass1))]
```

Implementation of GetEnumerator() will need to yield only once in that case.